# Reading from StringIO without resetting position

Tags: python, stringio, cstringio

I have a test code with the following:

```
with open('master.log') as f:
    print(f.read(8))
    print(f.read(8))
```

This prints as:

```
>> pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/Program $ sudo python test.py
>> 12/29/20
>> 17 12:52
```

This has different prints as you can see. However, when I do this:

```
import cStringIO

stream= "1234567890"
print(cStringIO.StringIO(stream).read(8))
print(cStringIO.StringIO(stream).read(8))
```

When I run this, I get this following output:

```
>> pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/Program $ sudo python test.py
>> 12345678
>> 12345678
```

In this case, it outputs the same values (the seeker doesn't advance).

I need to make it so cStringIO (or a similar solution) reads strings the same way as files. Without resetting the position every read I mean.

Comment: You're creating a *whole new* StringIO object every time you run `cStringIO.StringIO(stream)`. If you used the same one twice, the position would be retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael Butscher and other's have eluded to, you need to make an instance of the stream.

```
>>> #import io                                      # python 3
>>> import cStringIO as io                          # python 2 
>>> stream = "1234567890"
>>> f = io.StringIO(stream)
>>> f.read(8)
'12345678'
>>> f.read(8)
'90'
```

Comment: Might consider `import cStringIO as io` so selecting the appropriate `import` line is the only version-specific change. At that point, one could use a `try`/`except ImportError` to switch between them.

Comment: Nice idea.  Thanks.

Comment: I was having trouble with this for ages. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You construct a `StringIO` object twice which is equal to opening the same file twice. Assign the object to e.g. `f`and call `f.read()` twice.